# Inside UIStackView UILabel not word warpped to next line

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistackview

Below is my screen configured in Xcode storyboard. Inside the stack view, I want the same spacing I did via using stack view, but inside each view, in the stack view the label text is not wrapped to next line. I even use IBOutlet to change the label number of line, but it didn't work.

```
[_label1 setNumberOfLines : 0];
[_label1 sizeToFit];
[_label1 setText : @"63882748343487"];
```

[image]

Comment: set numberoflines of uilabel property to 0

Comment: can you please show me constraints of Label inside UIViEw -> UIStackView

Answer (score 0):

1- You have to set leading/left and trailing/right for the label to wrap Or centerX & width ( proportional to it's superView ) constraints in addition to `.lines = 0`

2-  It's better to decrease font size for these labels as you have 2 labels inside a limited width

Comment: I had set leading/left and trailing/right for the label, I want same font size, if label text length high, then it can be on next line also